# ¿Cómo funcionan las tarjetas de prueba de MercadoPago, y qué datos poner en el resto de campos que no son el número?

Tags: mercadopago

Encontré en la documentación de MercadoPago que hay una serie de números de **tarjeta de pruebas** o "test card" para simular pagos **fuera del modo sandbox**. Entiendo que estas tarjetas son para hacer **pruebas ya sobre producción** como si de un usuario final se tratase. es correcto?

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/test-cards/

Pero no he conseguido hacerlas funcionar porque no se indican los datos a poner en el resto de campos como fecha de caducidad, etc.

¿Alguien tiene info sobre esto?

Además tampoco sé qué quieren decir con "Para probar los posibles resultados de un pago, utiliza alguno de los siguientes prefijos en el campo name de /card_tokens o en el campo cardholderName:"

Comment: Hola Sant, bienvenido a Stakcoverflow en Español. Las respuestas a las preguntas con la etiqueta [tag:mercadopago] están tardando un poco más debido a cuestiones internas de **Mercado Pago**. Mientras te responden, te invito a que conozcas un poco más sobre la comunidad, visitando el [tour] y las guías del [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 3):

Cito lo que dice el sitio de MercadoPago en modo **Sandbox**

> Elige entre diferentes medios de pago y genera una respuesta
>   determinada:
>
> **Dinero en cuenta:**
>
> El monto de dinero en cuenta es fijo. No se agota si
>   lo usas en más de un pago y tampoco afecta tu saldo real. Para probar,
>   *ingresa cualquier clave* y el estado será: **approved**. Tarjetas de
>   crédito: Puedes usar cualquier código de seguridad. Para probar, elige
>   una de las siguientes tarjetas de acuerdo al estado que quieras
>   obtener:
>
> - Visa Nº 4444 4444 4444 0008: approved.
> - Mastercard Nº 5031 1111 1111 6619: approved.
> - Mastercard Nº 5031 1111 1111 6601: pending.
> - American Express Nº 37000 00000 02461: rejected.
> - Visa Nº 4444 4444 4444 0024: rejected.

Te recomiendo leer esta sección, donde dice como usar las tarjetas de prueba en modo **sandbox**:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/basic-sandbox/

Espero te sea útil!

Exitos!

Comment: Creo que esto podría ser un comentario :P

Comment: Edité la respuesta para hacerla más completa.

Answer (score 3):

Las tarjetas de prueba permiten simular respuestas distintas para un pago realizado por ejemplo, si ingresamos los siguientes datos como nombre de propietario de la tarjeta, obtendremos resultados específicos.

- **APRO** Pago Aprobado
- **CONT** Pago en Proceso o Pendiente
- **CAL** Rechazado, Llamar al banco para autorizar el pago
- **FUND** Rechazado, Fondos insuficientes
- **SECU** Rechazado, Código de seguridad invalido
- **EXPI** Rechazado, Fecha de expiración invalido
- **FORM** Rechazado, Error en el formulario
- **OTHE** Rechazo general

Los campos mes y año de vencimiento pueden ser cualquier fecha valida ( mayor al día actual), el código de seguridad puede ser cualquier dígito de 3 cifras y de 4 en el caso de american express.

Comment: Pero estas tarjetas sólo funcionan en modo sandbox?

Comment: Puedes usarlas en producción, pero para ver una actualización de saldo deberías crear usuarios de test, en la documentación puedes ver cómo se hace :)

Answer (score 2):

Nadie te respondio padre, yo lo saque a prueba y error.

pone par alas tarjetas de prueba :

```
    securityCode:"123",
    expirationMonth:"12",
    expirationYear:"2017",
    cardholderName:"APRO",
    docType:"dni",
    cardNumber:"4509953566233704",
```

abrazo suerte!